# Creating database with ID in the range between 1-999999

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ddl

I want to make a database table with the Id range being, 1 - 999999.
I came up with:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(  
    ID int NOT NULL
);
```

But I believe `int` has a range (-2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,647) which is way too large. Would something like `ID int(6)` work?

Comment: Which database you are using..?? MSSql / MySql..?

Comment: What happens when you hit your 1 millionth record?

Comment: Im using MySQL.

Comment: See  : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-int/ and consider `mediumint`

Comment: Just to be clear, is there a reason you consider the large range too large? It will make no difference to the storage - no space is pre-allocated or anything like that.

Comment: Int(6) is an almost meaningless construction. Instead, you could just populate an int column with 999999 rows and then only allow UPDATES.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the check constraint to limit the values to specified range**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
ID int NOT NULL,CHECK(ID >=1 AND ID <=999999));
```

For more info about check Constraint in Mysql refer this below Link:-

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: Note this will not affect the underlying storage. This will be 4bytes regardless of the value stored.

Answer (score 0):

YES, as per MS Sql Server integer max length it will support

If you want set limit of int value range 
use [check] as following Query

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
   ID INT NOT NULL CHECK(ID between 1 and 999999)
);
```

Comment: Note this will not affect the underlying storage. This will be 4bytes regardless of the value stored. Also note that , from comments, the DB here is MySQL not MS Sql

Comment: And the question appears to relate to MySQL (as clarifies in comments)